# Manifest Merger Failed for using the latest version of Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication, android-manifest

I tried to use the latest version of **Firebase** for android in my gradle file. I am trying to build a firebase phone number authentication but I am continuously getting this error, it's because I couldn't find specifically to my issue:
[image]

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

Here is my app:gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shimetaapp.shimetacustomerapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
//    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.11.0'
//    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'// Firebase Authentication
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
// Firebase Database
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.shimetaapp.shimetacustomerapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />

<application
    android:name=".activity.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ProfileActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.Purchases" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.PhoneNumberAuthentication">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[This](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) is the documentation I used to setup my firebase in my android studio.

Comment: Why are you using + notation for versions?  It's better to specify the actual version that you want instead.  Android Studio should be warning you about that when you look at your build.gradle.

Comment: I have tried that too but I get the read line  error indicator on the gradle versions. so I am now using `com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1-alpha7` (for all the native libraries)and this seem to solve this underlining error. by the way the read line indicator didn't prohibit me from compiling all the project successful. its something I just didn't get comfort with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version conflict between support artifact

`com.android.support:design:26.0.2` and `com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1`

Update your `firebase-auth` verison, firebase-auth has dependency of `customtabs` that is lower version of `26.0.1` in your case.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.2.0'
```

Comment: but the com.android.support:design:26.0.2 is not working in me. it shows an error that it's not found even from the internet. but your answer fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting this error now `com.shimetaapp.shimetacustomerapp E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
                                                                               java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zza(Landroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcelable$Creator;)Landroid/os/Parcelable; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzeg; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeg' appears in /data/app/com.shimetaapp.shimetacustomerapp-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes16.dex`

Comment: what should I do next? @Abhishek Aryan

Comment: fixed it by only adding 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'` 
 in my gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to Gradle file

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```